# How to prove: A geometric characterization of a $2 \times 2$ orthogonal matrix $A$ with $\mbox{det}(A) = 1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices

In texts on linear algebra, a standard example for a $2 \times 2$ orthogonal matrix is the rotation matrix given by
$$
R = \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
 \cos \theta & - \sin \theta \\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta
 \end{array} \right]
$$
which also has the property that $\mbox{det}(R) = \cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta = 1$.

It is interesting to know that the converse of this result is true for $2 \times 2$ orthogonal matrices.

In other words, it can be shown :

If $A$ is a $2 \times 2$ real orthogonal matrix with $\mbox{det}(A) = 1$, then
$$
A =   \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
 \cos \theta & - \sin \theta \\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta
 \end{array} \right]
$$
for some angle $\theta$. In other words, $A$ is a rotation matrix.

I saw this result in a book but without proof. (I assume that the proof is simple.)

Suppose that
$$
A = \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{array} \right]
$$

To proceed, we note that the rows of $A$ form an orthonormal basis of $\mathbf{R}^2$.

This gives the conditions
$$
a^2 + b^2 = 1. \tag{1}
$$
$$
c^2 + d^2 = 1. \tag{2}
$$
$$
a c + b d = 0. \tag{3}
$$

Since $\mbox{det}(A) = 1$, we also know that
$$
a d - b c = 1. \tag{4}
$$

How to proceed next?

Comment: You’re advertising in answers on this site that you’ve written a linear algebra book and you’re posting a question like this? What?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the orthogonality condition on $A$, namely,
$$
A^T = A^{-1} \tag{1}
$$

Noting that $\mbox{det}(A) = 1$, we can simplify as
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}  
a & c \\
b & d
\end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
 d & -b \\
-c & c \\
 \end{array} \right]    \tag{2}
$$

Equating like terms in (2), we get
$$
c = -b, \ \  d = a
$$

Thus, we rewrite $A$ as
$$
A = \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \\
-b & a \\
\end{array} \right]
$$

Since the rows of $A$ form an orthonormal basis of $R^2$, we must have
$$
a^2 + b^2 = 1
$$

If we define $$a = \cos \phi$$ for some $\phi$, then
$$
b = \sqrt{1 - \cos^2 \phi} = \sin \phi
$$

Hence, a $2 \times 2$ orthogonal matrix $A$ with $|A|=1$ has the representation as a rotation matrix given by
$$
A = \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
 \cos \phi & \sin  \phi \\
-\sin \phi & \cos \phi
 \end{array} \right]
$$

If we define $\phi = - \theta$, then we can write $A$ equivalently as
$$
A = \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
 \cos \theta & - \sin  \theta \\
 \sin \theta & \cos \theta
 \end{array} \right]
$$